# Pass a complex-number array image (64 x 64) from Python to Matlab

Tags: python, matlab

Anyone know whether Matlab engine API support this ?

- It is a (64 x 64) complex-numbers array image.
- Each number is a 128-bit complex-number. Python complex-number datatype (64-bit real-number + 64-bit imagery-number).

The total data size will be 64 x 64 x 16-bytes.

Comment: You can generally save arrays in a matlab compatible format within python using `scipy.io.savemat` ([docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.savemat.html)). If the complex type is not supported then you save the real and imaginary components as separate arrays and then reconstruct the imaginary array within matlab.

Comment: Not to be rude, but what about simply trying to do it?

Comment: Thanks for both. The Matlab Engine API communication is very slow. I finally ported the Matlab code to Python and run all in Python instead.  Passing a lot of complex number arrays between them is more troublesome than expected.